# Why does this works (googleIO acionbarherlper?

Tags: android, version, android-actionbar

So the code is following:

```
public static ActionBarHelper createInstance(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return new ActionBarHelperICS(activity);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return new ActionBarHelperHoneycomb(activity);
    } else {
        return new ActionBarHelperBase(activity);
    }
}
```

If my device is 2.3 (api 9) it shouldn't support Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH but yet it runs, why is that? If it had been a method I called it would have crashed. Is it because it is a public static final int and therefor added from to my code? Please give some general detail and not just a yes/no answer :)

Comment: The API level used to compile your code determines the constants visible at compile time. Since it is a constant it is compiled into the code.

Comment: Okay so it was as I stated and no nasty hidden supprises ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stefan pointed out, the api level used to compile the code determines the constants visible at compile time. For my case this doesn't give any problems as I just compare simple values. This only give problems if you use a set method that uses different constants and you happent to use a constant that wasn't possible to handle for your api version.